# NOWIN98 больше не поддерживается; не учитывается

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Собираю старую версию ogre3d 1.6.5 в visual studio 2008 
 Ошибка: `NOWIN98 больше не поддерживается; не учитывается`

Помогите собрать.

Весь код ошибки:

```html
Журнал построения
    

Построение начат: проект: OgreMain, .Конфигурация: Debug|Win32

Командные строки
    

Создание временного файла "c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\RSP00000379564384.rsp" с содержимым 
[
/Od /Oi /I "..\include" /I "..\..\Dependencies\include" /I "..\src\nedmalloc" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_MT" /D "OGRE_NONCLIENT_BUILD" /D "FREEIMAGE_LIB" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0700" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHa /RTC1 /RTCc /MDd /Gy /fp:fast /Yu"OgreStableHeaders.h" /Fp"..\obj\Debug\OgreMain_d.pch" /Fo"..\obj\Debug\\" /Fd"..\obj\Debug\vc90.pdb" /W3 /c /Wp64 /ZI /TP ..\src\OgreZip.cpp

..\src\OgreFreeImageCodec.cpp

..\src\OgreFont.cpp
]
Создаю командную строку "cl.exe @c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\RSP00000379564384.rsp /nologo /errorReport:prompt"
Создаю командную строку "rc.exe /d "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0700" /fo"..\obj\Debug/OgreWin32Resources.res" ..\src\WIN32\OgreWin32Resources.rc"
Создание временного файла "c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\TMP00000479564384.tmp" с содержимым 
[
2 /* ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "..\\obj\\Debug\\OgreMain_d.dll.embed.manifest"
]
Создаю командную строку "rc.exe /fo"..\obj\Debug\OgreMain_d.dll.embed.manifest.res" c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\TMP00000479564384.tmp"
Создание временного файла "c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\RSP00000579564384.rsp" с содержимым 
[
/OUT:"..\..\lib/OgreMain_d.dll" /VERSION:0.99 /INCREMENTAL /LIBPATH:"..\..\Dependencies\lib\Debug" /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"..\obj\Debug\OgreMain_d.dll.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCD" /NODEFAULTLIB:"LIBCMTD" /DEBUG /PDB:"..\..\lib/OgreMain_d.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /OPT:NOWIN98 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /IMPLIB:"..\..\lib/OgreMain_d.lib" /MACHINE:X86 kernel32.lib user32.lib zziplibd.lib zlibd.lib freetype235_D.lib freeimaged.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAlignedAllocator.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAnimable.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAnimation.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAnimationState.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAnimationTrack.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreArchiveManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAutoParamDataSource.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreAxisAlignedBox.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreBillboard.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreBillboardChain.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreBillboardParticleRenderer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreBillboardSet.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreBone.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreBorderPanelOverlayElement.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCamera.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCodec.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreColourValue.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCommon.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompiler2Pass.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositionPass.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositionTargetPass.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositionTechnique.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositor.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositorChain.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositorInstance.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositorManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositorScriptCompiler.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreCompositorSerializer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreConfigDialog.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreConfigFile.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreControllerManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreConvexBody.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreDataStream.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreDDSCodec.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreDefaultHardwareBufferManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreDefaultSceneQueries.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreDynLib.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreDynLibManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreEdgeListBuilder.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreEntity.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreErrorDialog.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreException.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreExternalTextureSource.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreExternalTextureSourceManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreFileSystem.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreFont.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreFontManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreFreeImageCodec.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreFrustum.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreGpuProgram.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreGpuProgramManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreGpuProgramUsage.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHardwareBufferManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHardwareIndexBuffer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHardwareOcclusionQuery.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHardwarePixelBuffer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHardwareVertexBuffer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHighLevelGpuProgram.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreHighLevelGpuProgramManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreImage.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreInstancedGeometry.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreKeyFrame.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreLight.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreLog.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreLogManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreManualObject.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMaterial.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMaterialManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMaterialSerializer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMath.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMatrix3.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMatrix4.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMemoryAllocatedObject.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMemoryNedAlloc.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMemoryTracker.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMesh.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMeshManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMeshSerializer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMeshSerializerImpl.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMovableObject.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMovablePlane.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreNode.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreNumerics.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOptimisedUtil.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOptimisedUtilGeneral.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOptimisedUtilSSE.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOverlay.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOverlayContainer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOverlayElement.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOverlayElementCommands.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreOverlayManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePanelOverlayElement.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreParticle.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreParticleEmitter.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreParticleEmitterCommands.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreParticleIterator.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreParticleSystem.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreParticleSystemManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePass.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePatchMesh.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePatchSurface.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePixelFormat.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePlane.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePlatformInformation.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePolygon.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePose.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePrecompiledHeaders.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePredefinedControllers.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgrePrefabFactory.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreProfiler.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreProgressiveMesh.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreQuaternion.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRectangle2D.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderQueue.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderQueueInvocation.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderQueueSortingGrouping.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderSystem.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderSystemCapabilities.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderSystemCapabilitiesManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderSystemCapabilitiesSerializer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderTarget.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderTexture.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderToVertexBuffer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRenderWindow.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreResource.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreResourceBackgroundQueue.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreResourceGroupManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreResourceManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRibbonTrail.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRoot.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreRotationSpline.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSceneManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSceneManagerEnumerator.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSceneNode.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSceneQuery.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreScriptCompiler.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreScriptLexer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreScriptParser.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreScriptTranslator.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSerializer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowCameraSetup.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowCameraSetupFocused.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowCameraSetupLiSPSM.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowCameraSetupPlaneOptimal.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowCameraSetupPSSM.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowCaster.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowTextureManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreShadowVolumeExtrudeProgram.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSimpleRenderable.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSimpleSpline.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSkeleton.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSkeletonInstance.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSkeletonManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSkeletonSerializer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreStaticGeometry.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreString.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreStringConverter.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreStringInterface.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSubEntity.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreSubMesh.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTagPoint.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTangentSpaceCalc.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTechnique.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTextAreaOverlayElement.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTexture.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTextureManager.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTextureUnitState.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreTimer.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreUnifiedHighLevelGpuProgram.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreUserDefinedObject.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreVector2.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreVector3.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreVector4.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreVertexIndexData.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreViewport.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreWindowEventUtilities.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreWireBoundingBox.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreZip.obj"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreWin32Resources.res"

"..\obj\Debug\OgreMain_d.dll.embed.manifest.res"
]
Создаю командную строку "link.exe @c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\RSP00000579564384.rsp /NOLOGO /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT"

Окно выходных данных
    

Компиляция...
cl: командная строка warning D9035: использование параметра "Wp64" нежелательно, он будет удален в следующих выпусках
OgreFont.cpp
OgreFreeImageCodec.cpp
OgreZip.cpp
Создание кода...
Компиляция ресурсов...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Компиляция манифеста в ресурсы...
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.1.6723.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Компоновка...
LINK : warning LNK4224: /OPT:NOWIN98 больше не поддерживается; не учитывается
   Создается библиотека ..\..\lib/OgreMain_d.lib и объект ..\..\lib/OgreMain_d.exp
freeimaged.lib(IlmThreadPool.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTileOffsets.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(Exif.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTiledInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfScanLineInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfAttribute.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfRgbaFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfHeader.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ) в функции __ehhandler$?find@Header@Imf@@QBE?AVConstIterator@12@QBD@Z
freeimaged.lib(ImfOutputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(IPTC.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginXPM.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginICO.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(TagLib.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(Plugin.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(BitmapAccess.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginEXR.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginGIF.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(IlmThreadPool.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ) в функции __ehhandler$??E?$_Iterator@$00@?$list@PAVTask@IlmThread@@V?$allocator@PAVTask@IlmThread@@@std@@@std@@QAE?AV012@H@Z
freeimaged.lib(ImfTileOffsets.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(Exif.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTiledInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfScanLineInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfAttribute.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfRgbaFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfHeader.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfOutputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(IPTC.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginXPM.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginICO.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(TagLib.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(Plugin.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(BitmapAccess.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginEXR.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginGIF.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfHuf.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfPizCompressor.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfZipCompressor.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfRleCompressor.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(IlmThread.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTileOffsets.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTiledMisc.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfB44Compressor.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfPxr24Compressor.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) в функции "private: int __thiscall Imf::Pxr24Compressor::compress(char const *,int,class Imath::Box >,char const * &)" (?compress@Pxr24Compressor@Imf@@AAEHPBDHV?$Box@V?$Vec2@H@Imath@@@Imath@@AAPBD@Z)
freeimaged.lib(ImfAttribute.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfKeyCode.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTimeCode.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(IlmThreadPool.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfScanLineInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfStandardAttributes.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfChromaticities.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfOpaqueAttribute.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfOutputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfMisc.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTiledInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfStdIO.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfRgbaFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfChannelList.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfHeader.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfIO.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginEXR.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(IexThrowErrnoExc.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Container_base(class std::_Container_base const &)" (??0_Container_base@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTileOffsets.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(Exif.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfMisc.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTiledInputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfScanLineInputFile.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ) в функции "public: void __thiscall Imf::ScanLineInputFile::setFrameBuffer(class Imf::FrameBuffer const &)" (?setFrameBuffer@ScanLineInputFile@Imf@@QAEXABVFrameBuffer@2@@Z)
freeimaged.lib(PluginGIF.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(PluginICO.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfOutputFile.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(IPTC.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Orphan_all(void)const " (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXXZ)"
freeimaged.lib(ImfTileOffsets.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base::_Swap_all(class std::_Container_base &)const " (__imp_?_Swap_all@_Container_base@std@@QBEXAAV12@@Z) в функции "public: void __thiscall std::vector >,class std::allocator > > >::swap(class std::vector >,class std::allocator > > > &)" (?swap@?$vector@V?$vector@_KV?$allocator@_K@std@@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$vector@_KV?$allocator@_K@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@QAEXAAV12@@Z)
..\..\lib/OgreMain_d.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 5 неразрешенных внешних элементов

Результаты
    

Журнал построения был сохранен в "file://c:\ogre\OgreMain\obj\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
OgreMain - ошибок 76, предупреждений 2
```

Answer (score 2):

***Первое***:

> **warning** LNK4224: /OPT:NOWIN98 больше не поддерживается; не учитывается

Что в переводе

> **предупреждение** LNK4224: /OPT:NOWIN98 больше не поддерживается; не
>   учитывается

Вы же в вопросе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 написали:

> **Ошибка**

По-моему вы **не** понимаете разницы между [ошибкой](https://ru.qwe.wiki/wiki/Compilation_error) и [предупреждением](https://www.viva64.com/ru/t/0080/)

---

***Второе:***:

Ваша ошибка же - здесь:

```
freeimaged.lib(IlmThreadPool.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ ""__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base::~_Container_base(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base@std@@QAE@XZ)"
```

Это - [**ошибка линковки**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=vs-2019), т.е., либо вы **неправильную библиотеку подключили** (несовпадение версий), или (что наиболее вероятно) **неправильно её подключили** к проекту. 

Как итог, линковщик не видит *.lib* файл.